# Count duplicated values, delete duplicates and keep count and other columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, large-data

I'm setting up a data-set of about 10 000 rows and 55 columns from a excel file format. I pick out the relevant column to be displayed (Number and Date).

Now, the column "Number" has many duplicated values that i want to count and then remove the duplicates. In the same time i want to show the latest date the number was used.

Put in an example:

```
Column 1 = Numbers [445, 446, 447, 449, 445, 451, 445, 466, 449, ...]
Column 2 = Date [4/26/2019,3/26/2019,3/15/2019,2/26/2019,12/26/2018,12/16/2018,11/26/2018,11/6/2018,11/01/2019,... ]
```

445 and 447 is duplicated values; 445 is counted 3 times and 449 is counted 2 times at different dates.

The table i want to create is then:

```
Column 1 = Numbers [445, 446, 447, 449, 451, 466, ...]
Column 2 = Date [4/26/2019,3/26/2019,3/15/2019,2/26/2019,12/16/2018,11/6/2018,,...]
Column 3 = Count [3,1,1,2,1,1,...]
```

I.e. the date to be kept in the new table is the latest date when the number is used.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r'ImportedFile.xlsx', header = 0)
df = data[['Number','Date']]
sold_total = df.pivot_table(index=['Number'], aggfunc='size')
```

What to be next?
Thanks

Comment: Check the shape of the `df`, then use [drop_duplicates()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with `keep='last'` and subtract the new shape from the old

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Count']=df.groupby('Column_1').transform('count')
df=df.drop_duplicates('Column_1')
print(df)
```

---

```
   Column_1   Column_2  Count
0       445 2019-04-26      3
1       446 2019-03-26      1
2       447 2019-03-15      1
3       449 2019-02-26      2
5       451 2018-12-16      1
7       466 2018-11-06      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
# thanks anky_91 for reset_index()
df.groupby('Number').Date.agg(['max', 'count']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+---------+
|    |   Number | max                 |   count |
|----+----------+---------------------+---------|
|  0 |      445 | 2019-04-26 00:00:00 |       3 |
|  1 |      446 | 2019-03-26 00:00:00 |       1 |
|  2 |      447 | 2019-03-15 00:00:00 |       1 |
|  3 |      449 | 2019-11-01 00:00:00 |       2 |
|  4 |      451 | 2018-12-16 00:00:00 |       1 |
|  5 |      466 | 2018-11-06 00:00:00 |       1 |
+----+----------+---------------------+---------+
```

Comment: How do you autoformat to string with nice-looking SQL-style tables?

Comment: @ifly6: I use the `tabulate` package.